# How i can sync list and int in multiprocessings?

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have code like this:

```py
urls = []
data = []
data_counter = 0


def get_data(url):
    with requests.Session() as session:
        response = session.get(url, params=params).json()

    items = {
        'A': a,
        'B': b,
        'C': c,
        'D': d,
        'E': e
    }
    data.append(items)

    print('DONE №{}: {}'.format(data_counter, url))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Pool() as pool:
        for url in urls:
            pool.apply_async(get_data, (url,))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```

`get()` and `wait()` do not work, because then each process runs in turn, and not at the same time.

So, what should I do so that the `data` contains data from all of processes and the `counter` displays the correct result?

Comment: Do you mean to increment the counter somewhere? And what's the problem? The programs exiting before all the tasks are done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the multiprocessing library creates a new process for you, it uses an operating system level function called `fork`. This creates a new process that still has access to the memory of the parent process, but as soon as either side changes anything, the data is copied over to the child process's memory first. What this means is that changes you make to variables from the child process are not going to be visible in the parent process, which is why `data` doesn't appear to update.

To get what you want, you will either need to use some form of shared memory data structure (look into [multiprocessing.Manager](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#managers) and [multiprocessing.Value](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes)), or you will need to `return (data, data_counter)` from `get_data` and do something like the following to merge it all together in the parent process:

```
results = list()
for url in urls:
    results.append(pool.apply_async(get_data, (url,)))
for result in results:
    new_data, new_data_counter = result.get()
    data.extend(new_data)
    global data_counter
    data_counter += new_data_counter
```

(You will also need to make sure that `data` is cleared and `data_counter` set to 0 at the beginning of `get_data` to avoid duplicates being appended in `extend` and for the counter to work correctly.)